# Wordpress comments and Facebook comments

Tags: facebook, comments

I've just installed Wordpress for a travel blog. I want the visitors to be able to comment with their facebook account or sign up as a subscriber to the blog (my mom for example doesn't have facebook).

I installed the "Facebook Comments for WordPress" plugin but the problem is that now the visitors can either comment at the Facebook comments or the original comments. I want them to merge so that you comment in one place but you can either login to the blog or login to facebook to comment.

Anyone know if this is possible without me needing to develop?

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is (or show us an example), this sentence is confusing: "the problem is that now the visitors can either comment at the Facebook comments or the original comments."

Comment: Ofc. I mean that when I activated "Facebook comments for wordpress" a second "box" appeared at the bottom of the blog post. So there is 2 places for commenting the blog post. The original one for "WordPress comments" and a second one for Facebook comments.

Edit: I just want 1 box for comments but I want people to either comment with their facebook account or their account on my blog.

Comment: The Problem Tiax talks about is: If you enable the Facbook Comments Plugin you get two possibilities to comment: One from Facebook and one in the original Wordpress. He (and me) are searching for a possibility to unify these possibilities: Comments from Facebook and from none-facebook-users on my Blog should be merged. Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473415/merge-wordpress-comments-with-facebook-comments

Answer (score 1):

I've used these two plugins:

1) [Disqus Commenting Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/) - the easiest way to add facebook functionality to your wordpress blog:

They allow a whole host of features including facebook, twitter, google login/commenting and some other cool stuff. It will probably be more than you need but you might like the extras and the easy setup.

2) [Simple Facebook Connect Plugin:](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/)

This one is more targeted to facebook and allows a more piecemeal approach to adding functionality but is harder to integrate with your theme and setup.

Comment: Disqus is disabling the original comments for the blog, so that users who is registered cannot comment (if they don't have facebook, twitter or the other integrated disqus accounts). So that's no good for me. I basically want the original comment functionality but the possibility to authenticate through facebook.

Comment: you can allow guests to comment with Disqus (so they don't need an account). Did you go with Simple FCP then?

Answer (score 1):

Try the 1.0 version of Simple Facebook Connect. It handles things a lot better than the older version did. And the comments stay on your site, unlike Disqus or Facebook Comments.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect